# root user able to access and install repositories while non-root user cannot

Tags: centos, networking, proxy, non-root-user

I am fairly new to `Linux`. I have installed `CentOs 8`, and have configured the system to access the network and internet, by putting in the proxy in the network settings configuration in `CentOs GUI`, which is a `.pac` file. I also have a couple of proxies which I can, and do use with `export_http` and `export_https` terminal commands.

Network and internet access works fine, I am able to ping the machine, Firefox is able to connect to the internet etc.

For some reason though, my administrator user, is unable to use curl or access any repositories using `yun` or `dnf`. I have checked and set correct `proxies` but to no avail.
Weirdly enough, the same settings work for my `root` user.

It is perplexing because I used exactly the same settings on another `CentOs 8` system a couple of days ago, and that works fine with any user.

I did not modify the `yum` file, I hadn't even in my previous system (which worked fine). Is there something I may be missing?

Answer (score 0):

**root has free reign over the system.**

To make sure you have sufficient privileges for your non-root user, add that user to /etc/sudoers file; just as you find in the entry for root.

Then carry out the same commands using

```
sudo <your command>
```

Comment: User is part of `wheel` group, which, as I understand, should also have all privileges. However, it still does not connect to repos.